# Jquery append within appended html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have two functions add_spm that adds empty value (SPM), under each SPM the user can have several STATEMENTS. When i add a spm using the javascript function it works, and then when I add a STATEMENT under this newly created it does not show up in the html (altough being created), when I reload the page and call the add_statement function it works, so I guess somehow jquery does not read the newly generated HTML from the add_spm function (?). Insert statement and insert_spm.php are just inserting this information in the database and returning an ID.

```
function add_spm(spid, oid)
{
$.post('insert_spm.php',{ ci_caseid: '<? echo $ci_caseid; ?>', sp_id: spid, o_id: oid},  function(data) {
$('li#recordsArray_' + spid + '').after('<li id="recordsArray_' + data + '" class="list-spm"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><span class="editspm" id="' + data + '"><? echo NYTT_SPM_ADDED; ?></span><div class="clearboth"></div><div class="settinn"><a href="/cb_kobling2_koble.php?action=spm_view&sp_id=' + data + '"><? echo HENT_STATEMENT; ?></a><br><a href="#" onClick="add_statement(' + data + '); return false;"><? echo SETTINN_STATEMENT; ?></a></div></li>');
$('.editspm').editable('savespm.php', {});
});

function add_statement(spid)
{
$.post('insert_statement.php',{ ci_caseid: '<? echo $ci_caseid; ?>', sp_id: spid},  function(data) {
$('ul.sortable[spid="' + spid + '"]').append('<li id="recordsArray_' + data  + '" class="list-statement"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><span class="edit" id="' + data + '"><? echo NYTT_STATEMENT_ADDED; ?></span><div class="clearboth"></div></li>').find('.edit').editable('save.php', { })
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind dynamically created html to jquery use `.on` function of jquery

ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/

or you can use `.delegate` function

ref: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Can you provide some example code for how you would solve it?